# How create instance FileStream from FileStream?

Tags: c#, stream, copy-constructor

How create new instance FileStream without specifying other parameters in the constructor, instead of parameters from source FileStream.  How can I do it?

```
FileStream fs= new FileStream([any parametrs]); 

FileStream copy1= new FileStream(parametrs from fs); // First variant 
FileStream copy2= new FileStream(fs); // Or second variant
```

For example, I  create fileStream

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4 * 1024, true)
```

Now I want a lot of independent copies from it, but `fs` doesn't save any parametrs received from constructor.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It's not at all obvious from the question.

Comment: I want to create a lot of clone from a FileStream. But FileStream doesn't have constructor copy.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate the problem you are trying to solve, because cloning filestreams a lot sounds like very bad practise.

Comment: You want to process the same data multiple times, apparently. Why, specifically, do you think the best way to "reuse" this data is using multiple *filestreams*? For instance, have you specifically ruled out reading the file into memory once and then just running each of your operations off of that data?

Comment: it is necessary to work with a file in parallel threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this

```
class FileStreamExt : FileStream
{

    private string _fileName;
    private FileMode _mode;

    public FileStreamExt Clone()
    {
        return new FileStreamExt(_fileName, _mode); 
    }

    public FileStreamExt(string filename, FileMode mode)
        : base(filename, mode)
    {
        _fileName = filename;
        _mode = mode;
    }
}

   FileStreamExt fs  =  FileStreamExt(_fileName,FileAccess.Read); 
   FileStreamExt copy = fs.Clone();
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of intermittent file lock exceptions.

Comment: Why do you think that different clone from FileStreamExt have intermittent file lock exceptions?

Comment: When you are doing "cloning" like this - effectively opening file for read again. In theory `FileAccess.Read` should not cause locks, but I've seen all sorts of problems with this. A lot safer suggestion was given to you above

Comment: Will be nice if you give more information about the problems to repeat constructor from FileStream.

Answer (score -1):

What's about Stream.CopyTo();

```
FileStream fs= new FileStream([any parametrs]); 
var copy1 = new MemoryStream(); 
fs.CopyTo(copy1)
```

It should work

Comment: I am using Framework 3.5. Also not sure that new instance will have  the same parameter from constructor fs.